# Uninitialized constant of gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've installed JWT gem - https://github.com/progrium/ruby-jwt 
There is `gem 'jwt'` in `Gemfile`, of course. Inspite on that, I have the error of

```
uninitialized constant HomeController::JWT
```

in `HomeController`

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

 def method1
   @jwt_token = JWT.encode({.... })
 end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need a `require 'jwt'`.

HTH

Comment: how do I know in the future if I have to do require or not?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I can do that question justice. If you poke around your config directory you might get a feeling for why other files aren't required. Hope That Helps.